# Banach space is direct sum of closed subspaces. Do these subspaces become continuous embeddings?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am working on the following question:

$X$ is Banach. $A, B$ are closed subspaces such that $x \in X$ can be uniquely represented as the sum $x = a + b, a \in A , b \in B$. Show that $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}: \| a\| \leq k \|x\| \\ \| b\| \leq k \|x\| \hspace{2cm} \forall x \in X$.

I am completely stuck. I can't figure out how to use the closedness other than to conclude completeness of the space. Or perhaps to conclude that the projection maps will be bounded. But I can't proceed. Any nudge would be helpful.

Comment: Show that the projection onto $A$ (along $B$) is a closed operator. Then the claim follows from the closed graph theorem.